# Data types produced by apple watch

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

Does anyone have a list of data types that produced by the apple watch without any additional apps or integrated devices? It must be a subset of [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/data_types?language=objc), but I can't figure out which ones

Answer (score 3):

The exact list of data types depends on the model, but the latest Apple Watch models automatically collect data for all of the following HealthKit types:

- Active energy
- Basal energy
- Environmental audio exposure
- Headphone audio exposure
- Noise notifications
- Exercise minutes
- Flights climbed
- Heart rate
- Heart rate variability
- Resting heart rate
- Walking heart rate average
- High heart rate notifications
- Low heart rate notifications
- Stand hours
- Stand minutes
- Step count
- Walking + running distance
- VO2 max

Apple Watch will also collect cycling distance, but only if the user explicitly records a cycling workout. There are also other types of HealthKit data that can be recorded manually by the using the built-in apps on the Apple Watch, such as mindful minutes.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I thought swimming might be in there too, surprised it's not. Is this from some apple documentation, or just from your own observation/testing?

Comment: @JoeCavanaugh Swimming distance is like cycling distance; it only gets recorded if you record a swimming workout. I don't believe there's any documentation that spells this out but most of it can be discovered by wearing an Apple Watch and browsing your data in the Health app

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question!